# Program a unix kill in Java

Tags: java, sigterm

I am writing a unit test for a Java program, and I need to simulate a Unix kill. Is there any way that this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd written the rest of the unit test, but wasn't able to find out what command I could use to Kill the program from within it. Will try if the above (duplicate)answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, there isn't.

On a unix system, the best bet is to use [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29).